# WPF Flow Document Layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'm trying to print a WPF FlowDocument.  The layout needs to be in the form of 4 documents per page, laid out as follows:

```
 Doc1 | Doc2
-------------
 Doc3 | Doc4
```

(Sorry, I couldn't come up with a better way of illustrating the layout).

The page needs to fill, so if Doc1 & 2 are blank or just one or two characters, it still needs to print them the same size as Doc3 & 4.

The code I'm using is as follows (sorry it's long, I've tried to abridge where feasible):

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if ((bool)printDialog.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
{
    FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
    flowDocument.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
    flowDocument.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
    flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(25);

    flowDocument.ColumnGap = 0;

    flowDocument.ColumnWidth = (flowDocument.PageWidth -
                                   flowDocument.ColumnGap -
                                   flowDocument.PagePadding.Left -
                                   flowDocument.PagePadding.Right);


    Table myTable = new Table();
    myTable.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);

    AddCols(myTable);         // Add 2 cols

    TableRowGroup rg = new TableRowGroup();
    TableRow row = new TableRow();

    AddRows(myTable);         // Adds 2 rows

    TableCell cell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Doc1")));                
    cell.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    cell.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;          
    // Repeat 4 times      

    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    myTable.RowGroups.Add(rg);

    doc.Blocks.Add(myTable);

    ....
```

The problem that I have is that although this does print, it doesn't try to fit it to the page as described above.  Is what I am attempting possible and if so, how?

EDIT:

From looking [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/6_2009_8_0_0_1029107/Change-TableRow-height-in-FlowDocument-WPF.htm) I believe what I actually need is a way to calculate the height of the paragraph, so that I can set the Padding property.  Unfortunately the solution proposed in this link doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the entire block in a grid so as to give it the uniform layout and then place the grid in the block and block inside your single table cell. See if this works for you -

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

        Label text1 = new Label();
        text1.Content = "Doc1";
        grid.Children.Add(text1);
        Grid.SetColumn(text1, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(text1, 0);

        Label text2 = new Label();
        text1.Content = "Doc2";
        grid.Children.Add(text2);
        Grid.SetColumn(text2, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(text2, 0);

        Label text3 = new Label();
        text1.Content = "Doc3";
        grid.Children.Add(text3);
        Grid.SetColumn(text3, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(text3, 1);

        Label text4 = new Label();
        text1.Content = "Doc4";
        grid.Children.Add(text4);
        Grid.SetColumn(text4, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(text4, 1);

        BlockUIContainer block = new BlockUIContainer(grid);

        Table table = new Table();
        TableRowGroup rg = new TableRowGroup();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Blocks.Add(block);
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        rg.Rows.Add(row);
        table.RowGroups.Add(rg);
        doc.Blocks.Add(table);
```

Comment: I had similar thought myself initially, but I don't seem to be able to get it to print the grid.

Comment: Yes - as stated above I cannot get the grid control to print anything.  The code above simply results in a blank page

Comment: I threw the baby out with the bathwater here.  With a bit of tweaking this works (add row to rowgroup and set textblock height) - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own custom DocumentPaginator. See here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164033/WPF-Visual-Print-Component
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31834/FlowDocument-pagination-with-repeating-page-header
- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138233/Custom-Data-Grid-Document-Paginator

Comment: Yes - I've seen these.  Unfortunately they don't describe how introducing a custom paginator solves my problem

Comment: Could you generate separate XPS Flow Documents for each quarter of your "page", and then Print saying 4 pages per page, or get a DocumentPaginator to do that for you (as shown in one of the example links).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Convert xaml flow document to xps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this addresses my problem, unless I misunderstand the article.  What I need to do is layout the table evenly on the page - the page itself prints fine

Answer (score 0):

question, you added the cell to the row.cell and the rowgroup to the table, but did you add the row to the rowgroup?

Comment: Yes - it prints fine, just not where I want it to